# RabbitMq RepublishMessageRecover ignore ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Im creating a RabbitMQ consumer using...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

My Listener looks like this...

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queue")
public void getMessages(String message) {
    if(message.contains("error")) {
       throw new ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException("Invalid message, discarding");
    }
    throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("Re-queuing message");
}
```

Im expecting `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` to discard the message totally but it keeps ending up on the deadletter queue :( Heres my configuration

```
@Bean
public RepublishMessageRecoverer republishMessageRecoverer(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    RepublishMessageRecoverer republishMessageRecoverer = new RepublishMessageRecoverer(rabbitTemplate,"exchange", "deadletter_routing_key");
    return republishMessageRecoverer;
}

Bean
public SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy() {
   Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> includeExceptions = new HashMap<>();
   includeExceptions.put(ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException.class, false);
   includeExceptions.put(AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException.class, true);
   return new SimpleRetryPolicy(5, includeExceptions, true);
}

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
  SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy, RepublishMessageRecoverer republishMessageRecoverer) {
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
  factory.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
  factory.setAdviceChain(RetryInterceptorBuilder
    .stateless()
    .retryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy)
    .recoverer(republishMessageRecoverer)
    .backOffOptions(5000, 1,
        1000)
    .build());
   return factory;
}
```

Is there a way I can exclude the `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` from the recoverer?

Thanks